# How does Google plus page loading work

Tags: web-development

On Google plus, when I click on a Google plus profile or any Google plus link the page gets redirected to that link without a full page load but the URL changed and a record added to browser history.

How this can be done? Is there any tutorial or document?

Comment: See [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4015613)

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate as a Stackoverflow question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess this is done with the [HTML5 History API](http://html5demos.com/history). I don't really have anything to back that up, other than than [Github works this way.](http://warpspire.com/talks/responsive/)

There's several topics adressing this here already. Look at the links provided or those topics for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`history.pushState()` should do what you want.  The Mozilla Developer Network provides more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history.  Keep in mind there may be browser support issues depending on what browsers you want to your website to work in.